# processing the input in haskell

Tags: haskell, input, head

I need to get an input until the empty line is entered and when the empty line is entered I need to print all first characters of each line (as one word).
Can somebody explain what should I write in the last line?

```
inp :: IO String
inp
   = do
      line <- getLine
      if null line
         then return ""
         else do
            lines <- inp
            return lines????
```

Comment: i have exam in two days and i am preparing for it. It is true. Believe or not. and i need help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't want to spoil everything, but here are a few hints:

1. `String` is actually just another name for `[Char]`.
2. You can construct a new list that's just like an old one, but with a new element tacked onto the front with the `(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]` function (and in particular, `(:) :: Char -> String -> String`). You can read this function aloud as "cons". For example, `1:[2,3,4]` is the same as `[1,2,3,4]`, and `'a':"bcd"` is the same as `"abcd"`.
3. When you're certain a list isn't empty, you can ask for its first element with the `head :: [a] -> a` function (and in particular, `head :: String -> Char`).
4. As an alternative strategy, you might want to look into [pattern matching](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/patterns.html) instead of using `null` and `if`/`then`/`else`; this also eliminates the need for `head`, which is often a code smell.

From a comment, you've also tried something like this as your last line:

```
return head(lines) : []
```

The main problem here is that `return` is not a keyword in Haskell, it's just a plain old function. So if your argument is an expression, you need to parenthesize it (or use one of the various tricks for avoiding parentheses):

```
return (head(lines) : [])
return (head lines : [])
return $ head lines : []
return [head lines]
let answer = head lines : [] in return answer
```

etc. This should get you to where things typecheck and run; then you can get started correcting the bugs in the behavior of the code. =)

Comment: thats very good, but i still do not know what to write in the last line, because i am getting errors while compiling the code.

Comment: @Bob If you have something you've tried that didn't work, you should tell us the exact code you tried and the exact error you got.

Comment: for example: return head(lines) : [] last line. and the error is Couldn't match expected type `IO String' with actual type `[a0]'